# Alternative matches in regular expressions

Tags: python, regex

How do I find the text between the first `D:` either at the beginning or preceded by a space and the next space or the end of the line?

```
Text                                     Result
--------------------------------------------------
D:10mm                                   10mm
D:3/4"                                   3/4"
one two three D:12.34mm one two three    12.34mm
one two three D:3/4" one two three       3/4"
WordWithD:inside D:123 WordWithD:inside  123
```

`*D:(.+?)` only works when the text is both preceded and succeeded by a space, but I wasn't able to create one that manages all the cases on the table above.

I'm interested both on the answer to this specific question and on the generic way to match two (or more) alternative patterns. In this case I want to match either the next space or the next end of line, but I might want to match either `abc` or `def`.

Comment: Maybe [`(?<!\S)D:\S+`](https://regex101.com/r/ziGce6/1) to match `D` that is preceded with whitespace and then matches `:` and 1+ non-whitespace chars? What are the expected matches?

Comment: `D:(\d\S*)` [Demo](https://www.regex101.com/r/qAYwKB/2)

Comment: @stenci: If that is feedback for my comment, I do not get it. What are expected matches?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this:

```
\bD:(\S+)
```

Regex Demo: https://regex101.com/r/2B1mHh/3

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
\bD:(.+)
```

where `\b` is a word boundary that assumes there is no other word character before `D`